# How do I set the layout_columnWeight and layout_rowWeight programatically in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.android

I tried using the following bit of code, but to no avail.

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
layoutParams.Width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
layoutParams.Height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
layoutParams.ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
layoutParams.RowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
```

For reference, this is the grid layout under which it's added

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblNaslovRate"
        android:id="@+id/GridRate"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:columnCount="3"
            app:rowCount="5"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`layout_columnWeight` and `layout_rowWeight`. These two properties are attached to the children of GirdLayout. Just like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblNaslovRate"
        android:id="@+id/GridRate"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="2"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
    
    <TextView  android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               app:layout_columnWeight="1"
               app:layout_rowWeight="1"
               app:layout_column="0"
               app:layout_row="0"
               android:text="Cell 0"/>
     ....

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

If you want to set them programmatically, you can add this to your code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    
    var gl = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.GridRate);
    for (int i = 0; i < gl.RowCount; i++)
    {
        GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(i, 1f);
        for (int j = 0; j < gl.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            GridLayout.Spec colSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(j, 1f);
            TextView tvChild = new TextView(this);
            tvChild.Text = "111";

            GridLayout.LayoutParams myGLP = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            myGLP.RowSpec = rowSpec;
            myGLP.ColumnSpec = colSpec;

            gl.AddView(tvChild, myGLP);
        }
    }
}
```

For more info you can refer to [GridLayout Spec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html#spec(int,%20float)).

**Update**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblNaslovRate"
        android:id="@+id/GridRate"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="2"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
    
     
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Remember to add the NuGet package and search for `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.GridLayout`. This is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcDdr.jpg).

**Second Update**

According to your layout, you can see [this summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta8WF.jpg).

Comment: Sun

Still the same issue, the weight does not apply and its all together on the left side of the screen. 

I've pasted the entire xml of the activity, if that makes a difference here. https://justpaste.it/bweby

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @makse Yes, your xml of activity is different from mine. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sun

Is the update that I should remove the relative layout? Because I have to leave it in. 

Otherwise the result is the same, and from what I see so is the code for the grid layout in the updated part of the comment.

Comment: @makse *Is the update that I should remove the relative layout?* No, the updated part is my own layout. This time I see what you mean. I updated the answer again.  Hope this time can really help you.

Comment: Sun

Worked like a charm, thanks mate, you've been tremendous help! Sorry for not getting it sooner! :D